# vim - multiple commands on same line mapping failure

Tags: vim

I am pretty new to vim/gvim. This is my first attempt at modifying the ~/.vimrc file.
I am trying to map F11 to multiple commands.
What I am trying is

```
    inoremap jj <ESC>
    map <F11> h e a , jj && l && x
```

While manually entering `h e a , jj l x` is working for me, using `F11` key is not.
What I am trying to achieve is-

```
1. get to the end of the current word
2. append ','
3. move right one place and delete that space between ',' and the start of next word.
```

I do not understand what's wrong with my mapping.
Please help me here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, let's build a proper representation of your macro

> 1. get to the end of the current word

```
e
```

> 2. append ','

```
ea,<Esc>
```

> 3. move right one place…

```
ea,<Esc>l
```

> … and delete that space between ',' and the start of next word.

```
ea,<Esc>lx
```

Second, let's use it in the right-hand part of a proper non-recursive mapping:

```
nnoremap <F11> ea,<Esc>lx
```

Of note:

- `<Space>` is a legitimate normal mode command so any `<Space>` in your macro is interpreted as "move the cursor one cell to the right", see `:help l`.
- `&` is also a legitimate normal mode command, see `:help &`.
- In a macro, every character is meaningful so `h e a , jj && l && x` is interpreted as:

  1. move the cursor one cell to the left,
  2. move the cursor one cell to the right,
  3. move the cursor to the end of the current word,
  4. move the cursor one cell to the right,
  5. append a space, a comma, a space,
  6. move the cursor one cell to the right,
  7. repeat last substitution,
  8. repeat last substitution,
  9. move the cursor one cell to the right,
  10. move the cursor one cell to the right,
  11. move the cursor one cell to the right,
  12. repeat last substitution,
  13. repeat last substitution,
  14. move the cursor one cell to the right,
  15. cut the character under the cursor.
- Your `jj` insert mode mapping provides zero value over plain `<Esc>` so there is no reason to use it in any mapping.
- Your mapping thus becomes a non-recursive mapping so `nmap` becomes `nnoremap`.

Comment: Thank you for putting in the time to provide a detailed answer as this.
I have not tried this yet but with the errors in my attempt so clear now, I believe this will work.
I have a long way to vim yet, what do you suggest other than `:help`, some tutorials or books maybe?

Comment: Vim's documentation is made of two parts. The reference is… well a reference but the user manual is mandatory reading: `:help usr_toc`.